How to search Row 1 for criteria and then select the column that the criteria cell is met?
I wasn't able to get too much help in my last question but I think it's because I was asking for too much all at once. So I'm breaking it down into steps as I code and as I reach problems I figured I can ask here.
So in this step of the process I am trying to search row 1 (it will always be row 1) for a specific criteria held within a cell. This criteria has values before and after it in the cell so I'm using wildcards "insert criteria here" so that it can find it. I then want it to select the column that it finds this criteria in. For example _1.D is always in column 1. So I want it to find it in A1 and then select Column A.
I think I have all the bugs worked out finally and it actually runs but when I go to run it, instead of selecting just one column it selects all of them.
Below is the code that I am using. The value of 1-3000 is arbitrary. I probably COULD cut it down but I wanted to give it as much space as I could as the data set sizes vary so it may end on column 100 or it could end on 2000.
Additionally: The next step is going to be to basically set the determined column as the new range and then search that range for a second criteria so it has to be compatible with being able to do that.
Function WorksheetExists(WSName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    WorksheetExists = Worksheets(WSName).Name = WSName
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Sub FindData()

Dim shname As String
Dim rs As Worksheet
Dim SampleEnding As Variant

Do Until WorksheetExists(shname)
shname = InputBox("Enter sheet name")

If StrPtr(shname) = 0 Then
MsgBox ("User Cancelled!")
Exit Sub

Else
If Not WorksheetExists(shname) Then MsgBox shname & " doesn't exist!", vbExclamation

End If

Loop

SampleEnding = Application.InputBox("Select Sample ending string (_1.d, _2.d, etc.)", Type:=2)

If Sheets(shname).Cells(1, 3000).Value = SampleEnding Then Columns.Select


This is what you need to find stuff on Row 1.
Sub FindInRowOne()
    Dim rFind As Range, sFind As String, fSheet As String, cFind As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wk As Workbook
    Set wk = ThisWorkbook
    fSheet = InputBox("Enter Sheet/Tab Name", "Which Tab to look on")
    sFind = InputBox("Enter text to find", "What to look for")
    Set rFind = wk.Sheets(fSheet).Rows("1:1").Find(What:=sFind, After:=wk.Sheets(fSheet).Range("XFD1"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If rFind Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Value Not Found" ''Debug Remove when done
    Else
        Debug.Print rFind.Column ''Column Number where value was found
        cFind = Split(wk.Sheets(fSheet).Cells(1, rFind.Column).Address(True, False), "$")(0)
        MsgBox "Value Found on Column: " & cFind ''Debug Remove when done
        wk.Sheets(fSheet).Columns(cFind).Select ''Not Recommended to use .Select in VBA
    End If
End Sub


This worked perfectly thank you so so much! One quick question: Is there a way to make it so it only selects a certain amount of rows in that column? Like selected rows 1-30?

Yes it can, Range(cFind & "1:" & cFind & "30").Select This should select first 30 cells on the column. I would suggest to read up on VBA worksheet Range instead of copying and pasting that to fully understand why it works. Or better yet, this is a very small and simple code, i would suggest reading every line and every part of it you dont understand you should google it to fully get what the code is doing. It will help in the log run.

Instead of this line:
If Sheets(shname).Cells(1, 3000).Value = SampleEnding Then Columns.Select

you can use:
Sheets(shname).Rows(1).Find(what:=SampleEnding, LookAt:=xlPart).EntireColumn.Select  

However Select is not recommended so it is better to continue without selection.
